# Generate random number except specified number in php

Tags: php, random

I'm generating a random number within 1 to 15 using the following code.

```
<?php
$except = '4';
$rand = rand(1,15);
echo $rand;
?>
```

But if the random number generated is 4, I want to print any other random number except 4.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a condition loop like this, you will get random numbers except 4:

```
<?php
$except = 4;

do {
    $rand = rand(1,15);
} while ($rand == $except);

echo $rand;
?>
```